# Can't the Relativelayout be nested?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

[enter image description here][1]I placed another Relativelayout in a Relativelayout, but the second Relativelayout cannot be displayed. Not only the button of the second Relativelayout cannot be displayed, but also the background of the second Relativelayout cannot be displayed.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/global_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.Typing">
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/functional_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:background="#DC143C">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="deleteHandler"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next_button"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="nextHandler"
            android:text="Skip"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/delete_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next_10_button"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_10_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="next10Handler"
            android:text="Skip 10"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/next_button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The output is like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwnGx.jpg

Comment: possible to show image ?

Comment: I have added my image to the quesion.@ Ajithkumar Muthukumaran

Comment: where ?there is no images

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake with embdding the picture. I have added the link of the picture in the quesion. Thank you!@Ajithkumar Muthukumaran

Comment: okey , try with my answer it should work

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/global_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/functional_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:background="#DC143C">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="deleteHandler"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next_button"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="nextHandler"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/delete_button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next_10_button"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_10_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="next10Handler"
        android:text="Skip 10"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/next_button" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think linearlayout has the problem of cannot applying to all phones. And the layout may change with the change of the phone. Am I right?

Comment: no it will work fine , or try with ```ConstraintLayout```

Answer (score 0):

try with this: Just put your second relative layout inside first relative layout,and put delete button to right of next_10_button.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/functional_buttons"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
       android:background="#DC143C">
          <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/next_10_button"
            />
          <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next_button"

            />
         <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/next_10_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/next_button"
          />


      </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is never a good idea to write nested RelativeLayout or any kind of layout for that matter. Try to solve it with a single layer of hierarchy.

The best solution would be to use a ConstraintLayout. The current ConstraintLayout is capable enough to create even the most complex layouts. So, there is a good chance that you will be able to do it as well.

[Give it a try](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I have a question, that is if I use ConstraintLayout and then I change a phone. Will the layout change as well? I use the relativelayout to adapt to different kinds of phones. I am not very clear of the problem. Looking for your reply!@Shubham Naik

Comment: What do you mean change a phone? Are you asking whether the constraintlayout will adapt to different screen sizes? Please go through the above link, it explains how to create a responsive UI.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that. It does not show the name, I assumed it was you. Anyways, were you able to fix your layout problem?

Comment: Yes， I fixed it by changing relativelayout to linearlayout. Thank you !